# How to construct maven project from source code

Tags: java, maven, disassembly

I have compiled sources of java web application. I know that project uses maven, because there is `pom.xml` files inside `.war` file.

I want to know is it possible to re create maven project using `.war` file. I use [Java Decompiler](http://jd.benow.ca/) to get sources, but i do not know how to combine all folders and .java files as it was in original project.

Is there any tool or howto to do it automaticaly?

[Here is](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6322771/) sources directory tree structure

For information: **I do not want to stole some project or code, it's just my work. There is some web app in our production that was done by other developers in 2007. Now we are supporting this projects, and i don't know why customers do not have sources.**

Answer (score 0):

Create a new project from scratch as explained in [Maven - Guide to Webapps](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-webapp.html). Then find the `src/main/java` directory and create a directory structure that reflects packages of classes in the war. Move the resources to `resources` folder. Use the command `mvn package` to recreate the `war`.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow following steps. If your pom.xml is proper

1. Create a folder say, project
2. Copy your source code files with package structure intact to project folder( Note: if subfolder should src /project/src .
3. Copy pom.xml
4. In eclipse File->Import->select Maven-> Existing maven projects-> select the folder(project)-> Follow the instruction